# Problem with Date based datatype using sqlalchemy with sqlite3

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy with sqlite3, here in one of the table I have a column with DATE as datatype and the format of stored DATE is "May 17, 1992".

The declaration of the table is as follows (just for reference):

```
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative
Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()

class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    user_id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    date_of_birth = Column(DATE)
```

And I have tried to query the Table as follows:

```
user = db_session.query(Tables.Users).all()
```

Here I get the following error from ORM(sqlalchemy):

```
ValueError: Couldn't parse date string: 'May 17, 1992'
```

Can anyone please tell how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure that SQLAlchemy supports custom-format date strings, as a workaround you can define your column as `String` type and then post-process after retrieving from database

Comment: It's best to stick with date formats recognized by sqlite functions (it does not have an actual date type). Read https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype and https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html